# Ffmpeg scale2ref aspect ratio preservation doesn't preserve the aspect ration exactly as desired

Tags: ffmpeg, video, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to scale an image overlay on top of a video so that it fits within the video but preserves it's original aspect ratio.

From googling around I came up with this:

```
[img_src][video_src]scale2ref=w=iw * 0.8:h=ow * dar[img_out][video_out]
```

This get's me pretty close however, the image is still slightly squished (The circle on the left here should be completely round):
[image: aspect ratio not preserved]

I've tried other variations using `mdar` instead of dar etc but this is the closest I got and it's bugging the hell out of me.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, like 2 seconds after posting this I figured out I should divide by the aspect ratio instead of multiplying. Leaving this here in case someone else gets stuck for no reason.

The final correct form is:

```
[img_src][video_src]scale2ref=w=iw * 0.8:h=ow / mdar[img_out][video_out]
```

Note the `mdar` instead of `dar` as well. That made more sense to me in the first place, but the rabbit whole got me close with `dar` by chance.

Comment: FYI, I had to use this to get mine to look right: `w=iw * 0.8:h=ow * sar` For what it's worth, my watermark is a perfect square.

Comment: I take it back, after a little more fiddling around, this is what worked best for me in **_both_** landscape _and_ portrait: `scale2ref=h=ih * 0.8:w=oh/sar`